# How to conditionally populate an argument value in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-gcp

I am writing a [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) script to spin up resources in Google Cloud Platform. 
Some resources require one argument only if the other one set, how to populate one argument only if the other one is populated (or any other similar condition)?

For example:

```
resource "google_compute_router" "compute_router" {
  name    = "my-router"
  network = "${google_compute_network.foobar.name}"
  bgp {
    asn               = 64514
    advertise_mode    = "CUSTOM"
    advertised_groups = ["ALL_SUBNETS"]
    advertised_ip_ranges {
      range = "1.2.3.4"
    }
    advertised_ip_ranges {
      range = "6.7.0.0/16"
    }
  }
}
```

In the above resource ([google_compute_router](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_router.html)) the description for both `advertised_groups` and `advertised_ip_ranges` says **This field can only be populated if advertise_mode is CUSTOM and is advertised to all peers of the router.**

Now if I keep the value of `advertise_mode` as **DEFAULT**, my code looks something like below:

```
resource "google_compute_router" "compute_router" {
  name    = "my-router"
  network = "${google_compute_network.foobar.name}"
  bgp {
    asn               = 64514

    #Changin only the value below
    advertise_mode    = "DEFAULT"

    advertised_groups = ["ALL_SUBNETS"]
    advertised_ip_ranges {
      range = "1.2.3.4"
    }
    advertised_ip_ranges {
      range = "6.7.0.0/16"
    }
  }
}
```

The above script however on running gives the following error:

```
* google_compute_router.compute_router_default: Error creating Router: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.bgp.advertiseMode': 'DEFAULT'. Router cannot have a custom advertisement configurati
on in default mode., invalid
```

As a workaround to the above, I have created two resources with different names doing almost the same thing. The script looks something like below:

```
resource "google_compute_router" "compute_router_default" {
  count               = "${var.advertise_mode == "DEFAULT" ? 1 : 0}"
  name                = "${var.router_name}"
  region              = "${var.region}"
  network             = "${var.network_name}"

  bgp {
    asn               = "${var.asn}"
    advertise_mode    = "${var.advertise_mode}"
    #Removed some codes from here
  }
}

resource "google_compute_router" "compute_router_custom" {
  count               = "${var.advertise_mode == "CUSTOM" ? 1 : 0}"
  name                = "${var.router_name}"
  region              = "${var.region}"
  network             = "${var.network_name}"

  bgp {
    asn               = "${var.asn}"
    advertise_mode    = "${var.advertise_mode}"
    advertised_groups = ["${var.advertised_groups}"]

    advertised_ip_ranges {
      range = "${var.advertised_ip_range}"
      description = "${var.advertised_ip_description}"
    }
  }
}
```

The above script works fine, however it seems like a lot of code repetition to me and a hack. Also, for two options (of dependent attributes) is fine, however, if there are more options say 5, the code repetition for such a small thing would be too much.
Is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much what you are restricted to in Terraform < 0.12. Some resources allow you to use an empty string to omit basic values and the provider will interpret this as a null value, not passing it to the API endpoint so it won't complain about it not being set properly. But from my brief experience with the GCP provider this is not the case for most things there.

Terraform 0.12 introduces [`null`able arguments](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements) which would allow you to set these conditionally with something like the following:

```
variable "advertise_mode" {}

resource "google_compute_router" "compute_router" {
  name    = "my-router"
  network = "${google_compute_network.foobar.name}"
  bgp {
    asn               = 64514
    advertise_mode    = "${var.advertise_mode}"
    advertised_groups = ["${var.advertise_mode == "DYNAMIC" ? ALL_SUBNETS : null}"]
    advertised_ip_ranges {
      range = "${var.advertise_mode == "DYNAMIC" ? 1.2.3.4 : null}"
    }
    advertised_ip_ranges {
      range = "${var.advertise_mode == "DYNAMIC" ? 6.7.0.0/16 : null}"
    }
  }
}
```

It will also introduce [dynamic blocks](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each) that you are able to loop over so you can also have a dynamic number of `advertised_ip_ranges` blocks.

Comment: I read about this in terraform website. Is it a good idea to use 0.12 beta version for temporarily writing the script and making sure to change once 0.12 is released? Also, do you have an Idea when this next version will be released?

Comment: Terraform 0.12 was originally planned for late summer 2018 but has had a bunch of difficulties so I don't think it's fair to try and guess a date when it might be released at this point. I wouldn't use it for production stuff mostly because they warn against it at this point and I have some horror stories from less stable Terraform versions a long time back. For now (and if it's just this specific thing that you want) I'd stick with your duplicated code and move to 0.12 when it's released.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is incorrect as 'advertised_ip_ranges' wont accept a null value; the solution to this is to leverage a dynamic block which can handle a null value for this resource and further enables the resource to accept a variable number of ip ranges.

```
variable custom_ranges {
  default = ["172.16.31.0/24","172.16.32.0/24"]
}

resource "google_compute_router" "router_01" {
  name    = "cr-bgp-${var.gcp_bgp_asn}"
  region  = var.gcp_region
  project = var.gcp_project
  network = var.gcp_network

  bgp {
    asn = var.gcp_bgp_asn
    advertise_mode = var.advertise_mode
    advertised_groups = var.advertise_mode == "CUSTOM" ? ["ALL_SUBNETS"] : null
    dynamic "advertised_ip_ranges" {
      for_each = var.advertise_mode == "CUSTOM" ? var.custom_ranges : []
      content { 
        range = advertised_ip_ranges.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

additional search keys: google_compute_router "bgp.0.advertised_ip_ranges.0.range" wont accept a null value.

Comment: Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange in general, do not use signatures in posts. Your user-card, which is displayed on the bottom right of every post you make serves that purpose. If you desire for your contact information to be public, then that can be in your profile page, to which your user-card links. Adding a signature, as you did here, is often considered spam. It's also contributing to you getting down-votes on this answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer